# NSFileHandle weird problem with iphone

Tags: iphone, file, nsurlconnection, nsfilehandle

i am downloading an mp3 file using NSURLConnection and saving it to a file . The problem is mp3 file is created (found the mp3 file created when using simulator), but i cannot access the mp3 file . Any ideas?!!!!!

This is the code i'm using

```
filename = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:save_name]; 
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filename contents:nil attributes:nil]; 

file = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filename] retain];// file is in .h

if (file) {
   [file seekToEndOfFile];
} 
[file writeData:data];
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to close the file after writing to it.

```
[fileHandle closeFile];
```